# MEAN - Doing Processing on Two different Mongo Collections on Express.JS Route

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mean

I am looking to create a new array using two different Mongo Collections.  I would like to create a new array using two other arrays which is populated using  mongo collections.

My plan was to do this on an express.js route.  However, I seem to be running into a problem which I think is related to the callbacks and asynchronous operation of Node or perhaps Java script I am not entirely sure.

I am new to Node and JS in general and I am thinking this maybe more related to the design of my application.  How would I go about designing this appropriately so that I can create a new array based on the data which populates two arrays from two different collections in MongoDB.

See my code below.

```
router.get('/add', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}), (req, res, next) => {

workoutsArray = [];
completedworkouts = [];
sortedWorkoutList = [];

Workouts.getAllWorkouts((err, data) => {
    workoutsArray = data;
});

CompWorkouts.getAllCompWorkouts((err, data) => {
    completedworkouts = data;
});

console.log(workoutsArray); //[]

// workoutsArray.forEach((element) => {
//     completedworkouts.forEach((element1) => {
//         if(element1.id != element.id){
//             sortedWorkoutList.push(element);
//         }
//     })
// });

res.json({data: this.sortedWorkoutList});
});
```

**Workout.js (Model)**

```
module.exports.getAllWorkouts = function(callback) {
    Workouts.find(callback);
}
```

Thanks for your help!.

Comment: One way is to simply move your `getAllCompWorkouts()` (and all subsequent code) inside the first callback. This is commonly known as "[callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/)" and a typical symptom of early node. Solutions are Promises and async/await.

Comment: I'll remove my answer while I review it again.